# Regex for different pair of html tags

Tags: html, regex, parsing

I need regex matching every pair of `<p>...<br>` and `<p CLASS='extmsg' >...<br>` to distinguish parts of chat conversation, which I receive as string in following format:

```
<p CLASS='extmsg'>16:30:24 ~ customer@home.com: hello<br>
<p>16:30:14 ~ consultant@company.com: hello to you<br>
<p CLASS='extmsg'>16:30:03 ~ sam.i.am@greeneggs.ham: how are you<br>
<p>03/06/2018 16:29:55 ~ bok.kier@ccc.pl: im fine<br>
```

I need it for parsing method.

Comment: using regex for HTML parsing is not [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1)...

Comment: what you *need* is to show some research effort first

Answer (score 2):

Don't parse HTML with regex, use a proper XML/HTML parser.

#### theory :

According to the compiling theory, HTML can't be parsed using regex based on [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Due to hierarchical construction of HTML you need to use a [pushdown automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) and manipulate [LALR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser) grammar using tool like [YACC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc).

#### realLife©®™ everyday tool in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) :

You can use one of the following :

[xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)

[xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php)

[saxon-lint](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint) (my own project)

---

Check: [Using regular expressions with HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

---

### Example :

```
xmllint --html --xpath '//p[@CLASS="extmsg"]/text()' file
```

Comment: EG: A user figures out a way to get "<br>" into their message; this would break the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Regexes are not suitable for this, as per Giles Quenot's answer. Using a proper parser is a much better way to do this. If you do receive messages in the format shown:

- One message per line
- Every message starts with "<p"
- Every message ends with "<br>"

an easier idea might be string-matching the start of the line in stead. I don't know what language you're using, but an example in javascript might be:

```
var inputString = "" // From wherever you get your data
var lines = inputString.split("\n")
for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var line = lines[i]
    if (line.indexOf("<p CLASS='extmsg'>") == 0) {
        console.log("Customer just said: " + line)
    } else {
        console.log("Representative just said: " + line)
    }
}
```

You can trim the `<p>` and `<br>` tags out too, as you already know how long they are.

**NOTE** This will break if the format of the data changes (e.g. a designer gets into the CSS file and starts using [BEM notation](http://getbem.com/introduction/), changing `extmsg` to `message--external`, and adding `message--internal` to the rep's messages). As it would if you used a regex or a parser. The best way to deal with this would be to get whoever is supplying the data to make you a proper API for this info.